# Is Magento_Text_Block's "_toHtml()" is the only option?

Tags: blocks, magento-1.6

The situation is that I have some piece of functionality, that I decided to design as text block. It needs to output some code at `after_body_start` on every page as initialisation code (some scripts), and also some specific parts of code into specific positions of pages.

So, initialisation code fits fine to the standard `_toHtml()` method and I can use my block as following:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="<my_type>" name="<my_name>" as="my_alias"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But what about other specific methods? Is there any way to write something like this:

```
<block type="<my_type>" name="<my_name>" as="<my_alias>" output="<my_method>"/>
```

And tell magento by this not to call `_toHtml()` but call only `my_method` of the block?

I tried this as workaround:

```
<block type="<my_type>" name="<my_name>" as="<my_alias>">
    <action method="<my_method>"/>
</block>
```

With this approach I can do what I want: within `my_method` set internal property named, for example, `methodToCall` to `customMethod` and then check in `_toHtml()` if the `methodToCall` is defined; if it is defined, then call it; or do initialisation stuff otherwise.

But it seems pretty bulky and unelegant. Should I use other block type (not `Mage_Core_Block_Text`) or it is even better to use a completely different approach? I'm pretty new to magento, that's why I do not know which is the best concept for this.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need that and your generic example method names are not really helping. Could be a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please try to be more specific in what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stranglely, no one could answer. According to `XY` problem - yes, maybe I do not need to do such things with simple blocks at all and a more correct solution exists (and it actually does), but the question was about basic block functionality, not the problem itself.

Basically my solution works as intended: you can call block's methods through `<action>` in layout setup. But a little bit of additional logic should be implemented in the block itself, cause after calling the method default `_toHtml()` will be called too.